# Expected value of Borel distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

Recall that the Borel distribution is defined by the pmf:

$$f_X(n) = \frac{(\mu n)^{n-1}}{n!} e^{-\mu n}$$

I have been informed that the expected value for such a distribution is

$$\frac{1}{1-\mu}$$

I have seen [arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_distribution#Derivation_and_branching_process_interpretation) that prove that fact using the Galton-Watson branching process, but it lacked detail, and I am pretty ignorant about the conventions.  So I am a bit over my head.  Can the expectation be evaluated from first principles?  I tried and did not get far:

$$
   E(X) = e^{1-\mu} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\mu e)^n}{n!} (n+1)^n\right)
$$

(by cancelling $n$, reindexing, factoring,).

Comment: Typo - shouldn't it be $f_X(n)$?

Comment: Oops, yes, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\nu = \mu e^{-\mu}$.  Without loss of generality $0 < \mu < 1$.  The fact that $f_X$ is a pmf means that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!} \nu^n = \mu .$$
(It also follows by the power series for the Lambert $W$ function, but we won't use that fact.)

Differentiate both sides with respect to $\nu$, to get
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{n}}{n!} \nu^{n-1} = \frac{d\mu}{d\nu} ,$$
or
$$ E(X) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \frac{(\mu n)^{n-1}}{n!} e^{-n\mu} = e^{-\mu} \frac{d\mu}{d\nu} \\
 = e^{-\mu} \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)^{-1} = e^{-\mu} \frac1{e^{-\mu} - \mu e^{-\mu}}
 = \frac1{1-\mu} .$$
P.S. Differentiating both sides with respect to $\nu$ should get you the variance of $X$.

Comment: Could you please give a bit more detail about the variance calculation? I struggle to find the value of an infinite sum there. Possibly it's because I didn't quite understand how you got the value of the first order derivative.

Comment: If you differentiate again, you get $\sum n^n(n-1)\nu^{n-2}/n!$, which is $(E(X^2) - E(X))\nu^{-2}$.

Comment: Thank you! But could you please expand on how you actually get to Var(X)? I'm struggling to get to the end from your given formula. .

Comment: You already know $E(X)$.  What you want to compute is $E(X^2)-E(X)^2$.